# Looking for alternative to email for sending automated weather alerts

Tags: email, data

We have a website that monitors weather conditions. A cron job runs frequently, which generates alerts if it's too windy/hot/whatever. We already have all this running with alerts being sent by email, on a shared hosting environment.

If we set up our own web server (most likely linux of some flavor), I'd like to avoid having to run a mail server, as we have neither the time nor expertise to properly maintain it.

I can apparently use an API to send our SMS-based alerts direct to that provider, but some folks want emails as well as texts.
Also, this data is extremely time-sensitive; the users must receive alerts reliably and instantly.

What else can I use to send out alerts? What other ways exist for getting data off a server? 
Can I send email from one user only, without even receiving incoming mail?
Or should we bite the bullet and use an external email handling service like Fastmail?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *sendmail look alike* to send email using external account (e.g. at gmail).
It should allow you (optional) easy switch to local email server in future.

You may consider

- [msmtp](https://packages.debian.org/stable/msmtp) for sending out emails via extermal email account
- [fetchmail](https://packages.debian.org/stable/fetchmail) for receiving emails (e.g. bounce messages about failed email deliveries)